# mouse direction setting on headless (mouse less) mac

Tags: mouse, headless

I have a mini that's running headless and mouseless.  I connect to it through TeamViewer.

All is great - except... The mouse direction defaults to Natural and I'm old school.

Since the machine has no physical mouse attached there's no mouse settings panel to change the direction on.

So - anyone have a guess of how to change the setting?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it from Terminal using

```
defaults write -g com.apple.swipescrolldirection -bool FALSE
```

`TRUE` to reverse that call & set back to 'natural'

You can test the current value using

```
defaults read -g com.apple.swipescrolldirection
```

credit goes to [Topher Kessler](https://www.cnet.com/uk/how-to/how-to-manually-change-the-scroll-direction-in-mavericks/)